# Laravel seeding preg_replace(): error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I was wondering if someone can help me.

I am having trouble seeding a database in laravel using seeder, it keeps throughing this error:

```
preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array
```

When running php artisan db:seed

the seeder in question is: GroupTableSeeder.php and the code in the file is:

```
<?php

class GroupTableSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run()
{

DB::table('groups')->truncate();

$permissions = array( 'system' => 1, );
$group = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'agency', 
        'permissions' => $permissions, 
        'created_at' => new DateTime, 
        'updated_at' => new DateTime
    ),
);

DB::table('groups')->insert($group);

 }
}
```

In the DatabaseSeeder.php I have:

```
public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();

    $this->call('GroupTableSeeder');
    $this->command->info('Group table seeded!');
}
```

I am trying to populate the Groups table with a user role I am currently using https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry#groups

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's the issue, but it looks like you have an unnecessarily array in your ``$group``. Try removing one of them and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, I needed to do:

```
Sentry::getGroupProvider()->create(array(
    'name'        => 'Agency',
    'permissions' => array('admin' => 1),
));
```

Instead of:

```
$permissions = array( 'system' => 1, );
$group = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'agency', 
    'permissions' => $permissions, 
    'created_at' => new DateTime, 
    'updated_at' => new DateTime
  ),
);
```